# How to dynamically populate Linked List with Fibonacci series

Tags: c

I have a linked list, which I wanted to populate up to a certain loop number. I have my code below is shows a Fibonacci series using a C Linked list.

Here is my code without any loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node 
{
    int count;
    int fibo;    
    struct Node* next;

}node;

int
fibo(int val){
        if(val == 1 || val == 2) {
                return 1;
        }
        return fibo(val - 1) + fibo(val - 2);
}

int
main (void)
{
    node f1, f2, f3;

    f1.count = 1;
    f1.fibo = fibo(1);

    f2.count = 2;
    f2.fibo = fibo(2);

    f3.count = 3;
    f3.fibo = fibo(3);

    f1.next = &f2;
    f2.next = &f3;
    f3.next = NULL;


    printf("f1 fibo : %i\n", f1.fibo);
    printf("f2 fibo : %i\n", f2.fibo);
    printf("f3 fibo : %i\n", f3.fibo);

    return (0);
}
```

Now I want to do this via a loop. How would I do that?

Comment: Why do you need a linked list for a Fibonacci sequence? And why is the recursive `fibo` function recalculating the entire sequence for every term?

Comment: when indenting the code, never use tabs because each word processor//editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest always use 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be seen, even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability, 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) use meaningful variable names.  Variable names should indicate usage or content (or better, both).

Comment: do you know how to implement a linked list?  do you know how to attach another element to a linked list?  do you know how to allocate memory via the `malloc()` function?  do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: the `fibo()` function does not need to use recursion.  just have couple of static variables that save the prior two calculated numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, I'm going to ignore the computational efficiency concerns that arise from recomputing all of the Fibonacci numbers up to the given number you are retrieving with each call to `fibo(n)`.

Linked lists are not usually "random access" data structures that let you access an arbitrary element with an index. When using a linked list with pointers, you only need to have the pointer to the *head* (first element) of the linked list. You then traverse the list starting at the head using a loop going through each `next` link. If a list is empty, your *head* is usually NULL.

You can apply this here. One way (there are several) is to define a function to allocate and set a single entry:

```
node *set_fibo(int n)
{
    node *fibo_entry = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if ( fibo_entry == NULL ) {
        // error
    }

    fibo_entry->count = n;
    fibo_entry->fibo = fibo(n);
    fibo_entry->next = NULL;
    return fibo_entry;
}
```

And then in your main:

```
node *fibo_list = NULL;
node *last_fibo = NULL;

// Assume n_fibo is the number of Fibonacci numbers you want to store in order
for ( int n = 1; n <= n_fibo; n++ ) {
    if ( n == 1 )
        fibo_list = last_fibo = set_fibo(1);
    else {
        last_fibo->next = set_fibo(n);
        last_fibo = last_fibo->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has already been answered, I would like to add something regarding the efficiency aspect of your code. As pointed out before, you do not have to calculate the fibo value by starting from the beginning, since you saved the latest results in the singly linked list.
So given you have the following list `1-1-2-3-5-`, you can easily calculate the fibo value of the new node by simply adding the fibo value of the two lates elements (i.e. `3` and `5`). Hence the value of the fibo value of the new node should be `8`.

Given the pointer to the second last element, this function will add add a new node to the list and set the correct fibo value:

```
void addNode(struct Node* node){
    struct Node* n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    n->next = NULL;
    n->count = node->next->count + 1;
    n->fibo = node->fibo + node->next->fibo;    
    node->next->next = n;
}
```

In order to use this function, you have to create the first two nodes in the list:

```
struct Node* n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
n2->count = 2;
n2->fibo = 1;
n2->next = NULL;
struct Node* n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
n1->count = 1;
n1->fibo = 1;
n1->next = n2;
```

If you now want to add - lets say 10 - new nodes, you simply do:

```
struct Node* ptr = n1;
int i;
for(i=0; i<10;i++) {
    addNode(ptr);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

If you now want to print the entries of all nodes in the list, simply iterate over the list until you reach `NULL`.

```
ptr = n1;
while(ptr != NULL) {
    printf("fib(%d) = %d\n ", ptr->count, ptr->fibo);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Please keep in mind, that you have to manually free dynamically allocated items!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the nodes are automatic variables in `main`. They are not dynamically allocated and they live as long as you don't return from `main`. You can extend this concept with a automatic array of nodes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    int count;
    int fibo;    
    Node* next;
};

#define N 30

int main (void)
{
    Node fibo[N];
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node **p = &head;

    int f1 = 0;
    int f2 = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        Node *nd = &fibo[i];

        nd->count = i + 1;
        nd->fibo = f2 + f1 ? f2 + f1 : 1;

        f1 = f2;
        f2 = nd->fibo;

        *p = nd;
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }
    *p = NULL;

    Node *nd = head;

    while (nd) {
        printf("fib(%d) == %d\n", nd->count, nd->fibo);
        nd = nd->next;
    }

    return (0);
}
```

It's not clear, though, why you need the Fibonacci series as linked list. Also, a word of warning: Don't mix nodes on the stack (like here) and nodes on the heap (as in lurker's answer) in a list. This answer just extends your answer to many nodes, whereas lurker's answer shows a more general concept of linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think you can do it. You can use an array for the nodes.

```
node f[3];
int i;

for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
{
    f[i].count = i+1;
    f[i].fibo = fibo (i+1);
    if ( i == 2 )
    {   
        f[i].next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        f[i].next = &f[i+1];
    }
}
```